Wedderburn radical of a ring
There is a little information present in the literature about Wedderburn radical of a ring. Whenever I searched about Wedderburn radical of a ring, it shows about Wedderburn-Artin ring theory or Wedderburn ring but not much about Wedderburn radical of a ring. I know that Wedderburn radical say $W(R)$ is the sum of all nilpotent ideals of a ring. Also, $W(R)$ is contained in prime radical of a ring. I want to know more about $W(R)$ and the type of its elements and its relation with other radicals like Jacobson radical.

https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/epdf/10.1142/S021949882150225X

This paper has some details about Wedderburn radical of a ring.
